# Project Management With Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

At my new company I have been tasked with setting up and presenting TFS as a full life cycle solution. I have plenty of experience working with TFS as a developer but I can't seem to find any good resources regarding setting up process via templates, things like modifying  work items templates,  creating sprints (We are using scrum) , bugs templates  and so on.  Any material either on the web or in book form would be greatly appreciated. We will be using TFS 2010 but anything from 2008 or 2005 would be a great help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN Magazine has an article about "Agile planning with TFS 2010" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347827.aspx

Also check out these fresh virtual harddrives pre-installed with TFS and Visual Studio. They come with labs that you can follow, one of them titled "Planning your Projects with Team Foundation Server 2010": http://blogs.msdn.com/briankel/archive/2009/12/23/now-available-visual-studio-2010-beta-2-virtual-machines-with-sample-data.aspx

Comment: There are newer versions afailable now both for 2010 and 2012. Only after downloading them (each 10GB+) I noticed that they are 30GB+ uncompressed and need Hyper-V to run. So.. you would have to install Windows Server 2008 (R2?) or newer, it also should work with Windows 8, all 64 Bit. That really hinders the experience. When using it the first time, you have to activate it, which should last for 6 months.